# How do I get total physical memory size using PowerShell without WMI?

Tags: powershell, memory, byte, wmi

I'm trying to get the physical memory size using PowerShell, but without using get-wmiobject.

I have been using the following PS cmdlet to get the physical memory size, but the value changes with each new poll.

```
(get-counter -counter "\Memory\Available Bytes").CounterSamples[0].CookedValue + 
(get-counter -counter "\Memory\Committed Bytes").CounterSamples[0].CookedValue
```

In general, this gives me a value around: 8605425664 bytes

I'm also testing the value I get from adding these counters with the returned value from

```
(get-wmiobject -class "win32_physicalmemory" -namespace "root\CIMV2").Capacity
```

This gives me the value: 8589934592 bytes

So, not only is the total physical memory calculated from counters changing, but it's value differs from the WMI value by a couple megabytes. Anyone have any ideas as to how to get the physical memory size without using WMI?

Comment: Just out of curiosity, why do you want to avoid WMI?

Comment: I'm avoiding WMI because it requires DCOM permissions, so a user without permissions wouldn't be able to get this information.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

If you don't want to use WMI, I can suggest systeminfo.exe. But, there may be a better way to do that.

```
(systeminfo | Select-String 'Total Physical Memory:').ToString().Split(':')[1].Trim()
```

Comment: Interesting, on my system which has 8GB installed (or exactly 8192MB), system info reports that I have a total of 8155MB.  I suspect that not all of the 8GB is usable by the system which could account for the difference.

Comment: Yes. Your BIOS may be mapping certain amount of memory for BIOS shadowing functions.

Comment: So the question is - what is the OP actually after?  Installed memory or total memory available for use by the computer?

Comment: I guess installed memory. Using systeminfo.exe, you cannot actually get the accurate value but that is the only option without WMI, AFAIK.

Comment: Yes. I'm looking for installed memory. Thank you ravikanth.

Comment: +1 Slight caveat: does not work on non-english OS, because the output is localized. But that's easy to fix, alternatively `(systeminfo | Select-String ' MB')[0]` did the trick for me.

Comment: Another Way using syteminfo with the format CSV option and converting to a structured powershell object to get the value

`systeminfo /FO CSV | ConvertFrom-CSV | select "Total Physical Memory"`

Answer (score 37):

Let's not over complicate things...:

```
(Get-CimInstance Win32_PhysicalMemory | Measure-Object -Property capacity -Sum).sum /1gb
```

Answer (score 22):

I'd like to make a note of this for people referencing in the future.

I wanted to avoid WMI because it uses a DCOM protocol, requiring the remote computer to have the necessary permissions, which could only be setup manually on that remote computer.

So, I wanted to avoid using WMI, but using get-counter often times didn't have the performance counter I wanted.

The solution I used was the Common Information Model (CIM). Unlike WMI, CIM doesn't use DCOM by default. Instead of returning WMI objects, CIM cmdlets return PowerShell objects.

CIM uses the Ws-MAN protocol by default, but it only works with computers that have access to Ws-Man 3.0 or later. So, earlier versions of PowerShell wouldn't be able to issue CIM cmdlets.

The cmdlet I ended up using to get total physical memory size was:

```
get-ciminstance -class "cim_physicalmemory" | % {$_.Capacity}
```

Comment: If the machine has multiple RAM banks installed, your command will return a list. The following one will show a total:
`(Get-CimInstance -ClassName 'Cim_PhysicalMemory' | Measure-Object -Property Capacity -Sum).Sum`

Comment: I replaced `Get-CimInstance` with `Get-WmiObject` for good measure

Answer (score 10):

Id like to say that instead of going with the systeminfo this would help over to get the total physical memory in GB's the machine

```
Get-CimInstance Win32_PhysicalMemory | Measure-Object -Property capacity -Sum | Foreach {"{0:N2}" -f ([math]::round(($_.Sum / 1GB),2))}
```

you can pass this value to the variable and get the gross output for the total  physical memory in the machine

```
   $totalmemory = Get-CimInstance Win32_PhysicalMemory | Measure-Object -Property capacity -Sum | Foreach {"{0:N2}" -f ([math]::round(($_.Sum / 1GB),2))}
   $totalmemory
```

Answer (score 3):

For those coming here from a later day and age and one a working solution:

```
(Get-WmiObject -class "cim_physicalmemory" | Measure-Object -Property Capacity -Sum).Sum
```

this will give the total sum of bytes.

```
$bytes = (Get-WmiObject -class "cim_physicalmemory" | Measure-Object -Property Capacity -Sum).Sum

$kb = $bytes / 1024
$mb = $bytes / 1024 / 1024
$gb = $bytes / 1024 / 1024 / 1024
```

I tested this up to windows server 2008 (winver 6.0) even there this command seems to work

Comment: I prefer to use the built in size constants to convert bytes to MB, KB and GB.

$kb = $bytes / 1KB
$mb = $bytes / 1MB
$gb = $bytes / 1GB

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/it-pro/windows-powershell-1.0/ee692684(v=technet.10)

Answer (score 3):

This gives you the total amount from **another WMI class**:

```
$cs = get-wmiobject -class "Win32_ComputerSystem"
$Mem = [math]::Ceiling($cs.TotalPhysicalMemory / 1024 / 1024 / 1024)
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

Using `Get-CimInstance` gives you the individual sizes of each RAM stick which you have to manually add up. Thus I prefer `Get-WMIObject` when possible:

```
(Get-WMIObject Win32_OperatingSystem).TotalVisibleMemorySize  # in KB

38326300
```

```
(Get-WMIObject Win32_OperatingSystem).TotalVisibleMemorySize / 1MB  # in GB

31.8008079528809
```

Answer (score 1):

```
 Get-ComputerInfo | select -Property OsTotalVisibleMemorySize
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe not the best solution, but it worked for me.

```
[System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("Microsoft.VisualBasic")
$VBObject=[Microsoft.VisualBasic.Devices.ComputerInfo]::new()
$SystemMemory=$VBObject.TotalPhysicalMemory
```

Answer (score 0):

Below gives the total physical memory.

```
gwmi Win32_OperatingSystem | Measure-Object -Property TotalVisibleMemorySize -Sum | % {[Math]::Round($_.sum/1024/1024)}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is not my creation but I found this and it displays the data beautifully in a human-readable format.

```
[Cmdletbinding()] 
Param( 
    [string]$Computername = "."
) 
cls 
$PysicalMemory = Get-WmiObject -class "win32_physicalmemory" -namespace "root\CIMV2" -ComputerName $Computername 
 
Write-Host "Memore Modules:" -ForegroundColor Green 
$PysicalMemory | Format-Table Tag,BankLabel,@{n="Capacity(GB)";e={$_.Capacity/1GB}},Manufacturer,PartNumber,Speed -AutoSize 
 
Write-Host "Total Memory:" -ForegroundColor Green 
Write-Host "$((($PysicalMemory).Capacity | Measure-Object -Sum).Sum/1GB)GB" 
 
$TotalSlots = ((Get-WmiObject -Class "win32_PhysicalMemoryArray" -namespace "root\CIMV2" -ComputerName $Computername).MemoryDevices | Measure-Object -Sum).Sum 
Write-Host "`nTotal Memory Slots:" -ForegroundColor Green 
Write-Host $TotalSlots 
 
$UsedSlots = (($PysicalMemory) | Measure-Object).Count  
Write-Host "`nUsed Memory Slots:" -ForegroundColor Green 
Write-Host $UsedSlots 
 
If($UsedSlots -eq $TotalSlots)
{ 
    Write-Host "All memory slots are in use. No available slots!" -ForegroundColor Yellow 
}
```

[Powershell ISE Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BnC5u.png)

Answer (score 0):

Tested and win32_computerSystem(cim_computerSystem) and win32_operatingSystem(cim_operatingSystem) both work when remotely querying virtual machines. The other options give fake results.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

There's lots of interesting answers here. On review I came up with:

```
(Get-CimInstance -ClassName "cim_physicalmemory").Capacity/1gb
```

Principally, it can be converted simply by selecting the required scalar value, i.e. 1kb, 1mb, 1pb or 1eb

Answer (score 0):

While querying memory across all our servers I found that the currently most upvoted answer

```
(Get-CimInstance Win32_PhysicalMemory | Measure-Object -Property capacity -Sum).sum /1gb
```

did not always give accurate results. e.g. it reported a server with 1.7GB of memory as having 0.5GB.

I found the following method to be more reliable:

```
[Math]::Round((Get-CimInstance -ClassName Win32_ComputerSystem).TotalPhysicalMemory / 1GB, 2)
```