# How can i get total Memory in % from task manager and get the output of it in to a log file

Tags: windows, amazon-web-services, powershell, memory, amazon-cloudwatch

I need a Powershell script that can get me total memory % from the Task Manager and get the output of it into a log file.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I see Windows and Powershell tags in your question. [This SuperUser post](https://superuser.com/questions/137701/view-memory-consumed-by-process-on-windows-7) explains how to get this information, both using commandline and Powershell.

Answer (score 0):

To get the total memory, try this command

```
(Get-WmiObject -class "cim_physicalmemory" | Measure-Object -Property Capacity -Sum).Sum
```

You can get this output into a text file using this command

```
(Get-WmiObject -class "cim_physicalmemory" | Measure-Object -Property Capacity -Sum).Sum | Out-File C:\logs.txt
```

---

<sup>Reference</sup>

- [Write output to a text file in PowerShell](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18469104/6327676)
- [How do I get total physical memory size using PowerShell without WMI?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17681234/6327676)
- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/out-file?view=powershell-6